# Getting bad request error while updating document metadata, Only scenario is when URL has special characters

Tags: sharepoint-online, development, sharepoint-rest-api, asp.net, office-365-developer

My URL is https://domain.sharepoint.com/sites/Test_list/*api/web/GetFileByServerRelativeUrl('/sites/Test_list/RE* FW_ SAMPLE Fw_ Vdr_ levering new books 4182885 - 0092870 *testing MM#00000* .msg')/ListItemAllFields

I'm able to upload but while updating metadata getting 400 response, URL after # hash is getting removed.

Comment: How you update metadata? Provide URL please

Comment: Patch request with below URL and https://domain.sharepoint.com/sites/Test_list/api/web/GetFileByServerRelativeUrl('/sites/Test_list/RE%20FW_%20SAMPLE%20Fw_%20Vdr_%20levering%20new%20books%204182885%20-%200092870%20testing%20MM%2300000%20.msg')/ListItemAllFields
 _httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("X-HTTP-Method", "MERGE");
  var content = new StringContent(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(metadata), Encoding.UTF8);
            content.Headers.ContentType = MediaTypeHeaderValue.Parse("application/json;odata=verbose");
 var responseMessage = await httpClient.PatchAsync(uri, content);

Comment: Try encoding request URL using [encodeURI()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/encodeURI) function. Let me know if it works.